# Should a counter column with frequent update be stored in a separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, denormalization

I have a MySQL/MariaDB database where posts are stored. Each post has some statistical counters such as the number of times the post has been viewed for the current day, the total number of views, number of likes and dislikes.
For now, I plan to have all of the counter columns updated in real-time every time an action happens - a post gets a view, a like or a dislike. That means that the `post_stats` table will get updated all the time while the `posts` table will rarely be updated and will only be read most of the time.

The table schema is as follows:
posts(**post_id**, author_id, title, slug, content, created_at, updated_at)
post_stats(**post_id**, total_views, total_views_today, total_likes, total_dislikes)

The two tables are connected with a `post_id` foreign key. Currently, both tables use InnoDB. The data from both tables will be always queried together to be able to show a post with its counters, so this means there will be an `INNER JOIN` used all the time. The stats are updated right after reading them (every page view).

My questions are:

1. For best performance when the tables grow, should I combine the two tables into one since the columns in `post_status` are directly related to the `post` entries, or should I keep the counter/summary table separate from the main `posts` table?
2. For best performance when the tables grow, should I use MyISAM for the `posts` table as I can imagine that MyISAM can be more efficient at reads while InnoDB at inserts?

This problem is general for this database and also applies to other tables in the same database such as `users` (counters such as *the total number views of their posts*, *the total number of comments written by them*, *the total number of posts written by them*, etc.) and `categories` (*the number of posts in that category*, etc.).

**Edit 1:** The views per day counters are reset once daily at midnight with a cron job.

**Edit 2:** One reason for having `posts` and `post_stats` as two tables is concerns about caching.

Comment: (1) Keep 2-table scheme. Set them to be referenced as 1:(0-1). (2) Use InnoDB and partitioning. *some statistical counters such as the number of times the post has been viewed **for the current day**, the total number of views, number of likes and dislikes.* - your scheme does not allow to obtain this statistic precisely. No mark which allows to define does the marked counter should be reset.

Comment: So, you seem to be saying that it's more performant to keep related data in separate tables and join them together every time you want to get the data back together. Taking it to the extreme you should thus have a table for every column - person name, age and address is 3 tables, 3 PKs and 2 joins every time you want all of one person's data. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: *person name, age and address is 3 tables* What of these person properties are frequently updated ones?

Comment: @Akina The views per day counters are reset once daily at midnight with a cron job. For now, the table is very small so I guess partitioning will not be needed as of now?
A bit more info: The stats are updated right after reading them (every page view).

Comment: *The views per day counters are reset once daily at midnight with a cron job.* Cron job cannot start with absolute preciseness, it may start not at 00:00 but at 00:00.500, and the hit addded in 00:00.250 will be lost. Formally. PS. Of course, this can be neglected. PPS. Why cron and not built-in [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html)?

Comment: @Akina Might be but the counting is not very precise anyway (crawlers, bots, etc) and is just for approximation.

Comment: @Akina I did not know about Event Scheduler, thanks for the suggestion. I believe that this is not the point of this question though as the nightly reset takes only a second and is run once a day.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am not saying I should go to such an extreme extent. My motivation was:\1. The statistics are not the most important attributes of the `post` entities and I can see them as a subgroup especially since there are many such statistical columns that will "pollute" the `posts` table.\2. The stats are updated constantly which might be a concern with caching.

Comment: @CaiusJard - (1) Age should not be normalized; it is as small as the id needed to fetch it!.  (2) You have to change 1/365 of the rows every day -- this is IMPRACTICAL.  So (3) store birthdate and _compute_ age when Selecting.

Comment: @Akina - Partitioning is unlikely to help performance.

Comment: @RickJames Partiton pruning may increase the performance seriously.

Comment: Yea,so that was a bit of an r/whooosh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For low traffic, KISS -- Keep the counters in the main `post` table.  (I assume you have ruled this out.)
- For high traffic, keep the counters in a separate table.  But let's do the "today's" counters differently.  (This is what you want to discuss.)
- For very high traffic, gather up counts so that you can do less than 1 Update per click/view/like.  ("Summary Tables" is beyond the scope of this question.)

Let's study `total_views_today`.  Do you have to do a big "reset" every midnight?  That is (or will become) too costly, so let's try to avoid it.

- Have only `total_views` in the table.
- At midnight copy the table into another table.  (`SELECT` is faster and less-invasive than the `UPDATE` needed to reset the values.)  Do this copy by building a new table, then `RENAME TABLE` to move it into place.
- Compute `total_views_today` by subtracting the corresponding values in the two tables.

That left you with

```
post_stats(post_id, total_views, total_likes, total_dislikes)
```

For "high traffic, it is fine to do

```
UPDATE post_stats SET ... = ... + 1 WHERE post_id = ...;
```

at the moment needed (for each counter).

But there is a potential problem.  You can't increment a counter if the row does not exist.  That would be best solved by creating a row with zeros at the same time the `post` is created.  (Otherwise, see IODKU.)

(I may come back if I think of more.)